# I tried using React using create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

This is what I am getting error message.

If anybody can help or can point me to

How to Create a webpage using React served via an express nodejs server without "create react app" or anything like that, just plain vanilla express server serving a react app bundled by any transpiler.

```
$ npm start

> writer-babu@1.0.0 start C:\Users\kiit\Desktop\writer-babu
> webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\kiit\Desktop\writer-babu\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kiit\Desktop\writer-babu\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:65:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\kiit\\Desktop\\writer-babu\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\bin\\webpack-dev-server.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! writer-babu@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the writer-babu@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kiit\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-26T05_15_56_534Z-debug.log
```

If anybody can help or can point me to

How to Create a webpage using React served via an express nodejs server without "create react app" or anything like that, just plain vanilla express server serving a react app bundled by any transpiler.

Comment: Try ```npm i webpack-cli```.

Comment: npm install or yarn

Comment: Actually got the problem, it was basically due to the current version of webpack, webpack cli and webpack dev server. I tried with older versions of these and now it running without any error.